# Service Fabric doesn't run a docker pull on deployment

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I've setup VSTS to deploy an Service Fabric app with a Docker guest container. All goes well but Service Fabric doesn't download the latest version of my image, a docker pull doesn't seem to be performed.

I've added the 'Service Fabric PowerShell script' with a 'docker pull' command but this is then only run on one of the nodes.

Is there a way to run a powershell script/command during deployment, either in VSTS or Service Fabric, to run a command across all the nodes to do a docker pull?

Comment: are you using an explicit version tag? don't rely on 'latest'

Comment: I’m not, will give that a try!

Comment: An easy way to do this; in VSTS, in the task 'Push Services' add `$(Build.BuildId)` in the field `Additional Image Tags` to tag your image.

Comment: And then how do I specify the tag in the ServiceManifest.xml in ImageName? I've already seen you cannot use application parameters

Comment: you can use a tokenizer to replace the value in your release pipeline. One of my favorites is https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme

Comment: How could I forget about that one! Now replacing #{ImageTag}# with BuildId after the Service Fabric project has been build and all works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please use an explicit version tag. Don't rely on 'latest'. An easy way to do this in VSTS, in the task 'Push Services' add `$(Build.BuildId)` in the field `Additional Image Tags` to tag your image.
2. Next, you can use a tokenizer to replace the ServiceManifest.xml image tag value in your release pipeline. One of my favorites is [this](https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme) one.

Answer (score 0):

to deploy docker containers to Service Fabric, you have to either provide a Docker Compose file or a Service Fabric Applicaiton Package with manifests.

For containers the Service Fabric hosting system controls the docker host on the nodes to run containers.

For VSTS deployments, there's a **Service Fabric Deploy** task and a Service Fabric Compose Deploy task for both paths.

Container quick starts for Service Fabric:
See her for Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-containers
Her for Linux: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-containers-linux

Comment: I’ve created two release pipelines, one with each task you mention. The docker compose version does do a docker pull, the other one doesn’t. So, any idea why the second one doesn’t do a docker pull? Or is this by design?

Comment: Sorry misread. The docker pull is done by the docker host in the cluster, after the application has been completed. Where do you see the docker pull? In the releas elogs?